# How do I resolve question marks on my login screen?

Tags: macos-mojave

When I restart or shut down and start my computer, I have the following. After sleep mode it doesn't show the question marks when signing into my account. Tried the advice below but it doesn't work:

Fix Font Corruption

Open Terminal in your Utilities' folder and paste the following after the prompt:

```
 fontrestore default
```

Press RETURN.

If this doesn’t fix the problem then paste the following after the prompt:

```
 sudo atsutil databases -remove
```

Press RETURN.

You may need to restart the computer for anything to take effect.

Using Macbook Air with Mojave.

Comment: is that a question or an answer?